# Where to place triggerInfo php file

Tags: extension, joomla

Joomla/CiviCRM.

Neophyte Warning!

I've written a triggerinfo hook as per this [article](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_triggerInfo/).

What I don't understand is where on the file system is one supposed to place the PHP file so that when one requests a trigger rebuild, the file will be found, and so that when an upgrade occurs the file will not be overwritten.

Can someone help me please?

Regards
Simon

Answer (score 1):

You should create an extension. See the instructions for [civix](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/). One thing that civix can do is generate a skeletal extension. After running `civix generate:module` you would add your code to the main php file in your new extension. See also [Extension Structure](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/structure/).

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your answer. Since all my triggerinfo php script does is call a MySQL procedure that I have written in response to an insert or update on the address table, surely an extension is overkill?

Comment: The SQL in the triggerInfo PHP script contains this:
  
    $sql =  
    "IF  (NEW.state_province_id IS NOT NULL
 AND (NEW.geo_code_1        IS NOT NULL AND NEW.geo_code_1 <> 0.0)  
     AND (NEW.geo_code_2        IS NOT NULL AND NEW.geo_code_2 <> 0.0)) THEN  
    CALL myfunc(NEW.ID,NEW.state_province_id,NEW.geo_code_1,NEW.geo_code_2);  END IF;  
";`

Comment: Yes but if you want to keep your code between upgrades then an extension is the best way of doing it. It's not hard to make a simple extension with civix.